# How to find a Facebook user

Tags: facebook, search

I can’t find a specific Facebook user (I searched his name) but if I log in with another Facebook account I can find this user.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Answer (score 3):

Probably he has blocked you. So you are not able to find him, but from another account or any other account which is not blocked by him, you will be able to find him.

When a user block someone, blocked user can not find that user and can not see any activity from that user on Facebook.